# Import realm in Keycloak:18.x

Tags: keycloak

I cannot import any realms into Keycloak 18.0.0. That's the Quarkus, and not the Wildfly distribution anymore. Documentation [here](https://www.keycloak.org/server/importExport) says it should be pretty simple, and by mounting my exported realm.json file into /opt/keycloak/data/import/...json it actually TRIES to import it, but it ends with :

`"[org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Script upload is disabled"`.

Known to be removed, and the old `-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled` won't work anymore. OK.
But then what's the way to do import any realms on startup? That'd be used to distribute a ready-made local stack without any handcrafting needed to launch. I could do it with running SQL commands, but that's way too hacky to my taste.

**Compose file :**

```
  cp-keycloak:
image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.0
environment:
  KC_DB: mysql
  KC_DB_URL: jdbc:mysql://cp-keycloak-database:3306/keycloak
  KC_DB_USERNAME: root
  KC_DB_PASSWORD: root
  KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
  KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
  KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
ports:
  - 8082:8080
volumes:
  - ./data/local_stack/init.keycloak.json:/opt/keycloak/data/import/main-realm.json:ro
entrypoint: "/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start-dev --import-realm"
```

**The output :**

```
cp-keycloak_1           | 2022-05-05 14:07:26,801 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (development) mode
cp-keycloak_1           | 2022-05-05 14:07:26,802 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to import realm: Main-Realm
cp-keycloak_1           | 2022-05-05 14:07:26,803 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Script upload is disabled
```

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This might be caused because inside of your realm .json there is references to some configuration that is using the deprecated `upload script` feature.

Try to removed it, export the json and them try to imported again (this time without the upload script feature.

From the comments (credits to [jfrantzius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1245428)):

> See here for what you either need to remove or replace in your
> realm-export.json:
> https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/11664#issuecomment-1111062102
> . We had to replace the entries, see also here
> https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/12041#discussioncomment-2768768

Comment: thanks you, keycloak 20.x still create default policy point to 'Js'. Delete it in Client>authorization>policies. We now can import/export this Setting

Answer (score 3):

In my case was enough to remove the empty code key from the default policy.
Removing the policy as mentioned in the link from @dreamcrash made the import fail since it was required by one of my clients.

Just changed on the realm-export.json:

```
  {
    "id": "b56eebd7-8e73-4449-b110-30dfdbc77f03",
    "name": "Default Policy",
    "description": "A policy that grants access only for users within this realm",
    "type": "js",
    "logic": "POSITIVE",
    "decisionStrategy": "AFFIRMATIVE",
    "config": {
      "code": "// by default, grants any permission associated with this policy\n$evaluation.grant();\n"
    }
  },
```

for:

```
  {
    "id": "b56eebd7-8e73-4449-b110-30dfdbc77f03",
    "name": "Default Policy",
    "description": "A policy that grants access only for users within this realm",
    "type": "js",
    "logic": "POSITIVE",
    "decisionStrategy": "AFFIRMATIVE",
    "config": {}
  },
```

PD: Im using keycloak 20.0.3.