# Keycloak 20.0.2: Error when exporting realm config for keycloak within a docker container

Tags: keycloak, quarkus

Very similarly to [Error when importing realm config for keycloak within a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73860390/error-when-importing-realm-config-for-keycloak-within-a-docker-container), I'm running keycloak in docker-compose, using the image quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.2 and postgreSql.

I'd like to export the whole Keycloak's data.

The following command:

```
docker run `
    -it `
    --rm `
    -v ${PWD}/keycloak-data:/export `
    -e LOG_LEVEL=INFO `
    -e KC_DB_URL_HOST=<containerName> `
    -e KC_DB_URL_PORT=5432 `
    -e KC_DB_URL_DATABASE=<dbName> `
    -e KC_DB_USERNAME=<userName> `
    -e KC_DB_PASSWORD=<password> `
    --network <network> `
    quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.2 `
    export --realm <realmName> --dir /export
```

seems to correctly connect to the db, but I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (import_export) mode
```

The error occurs both while the Keycloak server is running (with the docker-compose up command), and when it is stopped and removed (though, the postgreSQL is running, of course!)

How can the Keycloak data be exported?

Comment: Do you have javascript code? upload script option enabled. Is your realm declaring providers that rely on scripts such as mappers, authenticators, or policies?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/72128985/1366871 and tell if it helped you

Comment: @dreamcrash thanks for your suggestion, but the proposed solution seems not to apply to my case (I have no .json files created or edited by myself).

Comment: They don't have to be created or edited by ourself, it would also fail from those coming from KC

Answer (score 0):

The error reported in the question

> ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler]
> (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (import_export) mode

seems not to be relevant to the purpose of exporting data.

Configuring a proper bind-mounted path in the `docker-compose.yaml` file for the keycloak container and calling the proper command should do the job:

```
volumes:
   - ./myLocalPath:/export
```

then, perform the export, using the original container:

```
docker exec `
    -it `
    -e LOG_LEVEL=INFO `
    -e KC_DB_URL_HOST=<containerName> `
    -e KC_DB_URL_PORT=5432 `
    -e KC_DB_URL_DATABASE=<dbName> `
    -e KC_DB_USERNAME=<userName> `
    -e KC_DB_PASSWORD=<password> `
    <containerName> `
    /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh export --realm <realmName> --dir /export
```

The exported data will then be available in local folder `./myLocalPath`.